# WooCommerce COD charges based on second payment of deposited amount

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Our site has a deposit option for our clients. Right now I already added some options for the COD charge based on our second payment. So I want to calculate 2% of the COD charge with (_wc_deposits_second_payment) this key. Code I am using

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','cod_fee' );
function cod_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
        // get your payment method
        $chosen_gateway = WC()->session->chosen_payment_method;
        //echo $chosen_gateway;
        $fee = 0;
        if ( $chosen_gateway == 'cod' ) { //test with cash on delivery method
            WC()->cart->add_fee( '2% cod Charge', $fee, false, '' );
        }


}
```

Comment: Can you specify what you want to achieve here (you briefly did it), but also what you have tried and what makes you think it does not work?

Comment: Hi there I want to show a 2% cod charge of my second payment of deposit. I m using 3 options of fees but the COD fee is not showing and more two fee option is showing perfectly.